# ASP.Net MVC communication with Client Biometric Scanner

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, biometrics

Though there have been quite a good number of questions asking similar things, I could not find a reply with an example explaining the process.
My use case is:
 1. I have to make an MVC application communicate with a Biometric device.
 2. What I am having with me is the SDK for the biometric with a sample windows application explaining the working of the device. So, I can customize the sample code to cater to my needs.
 3. What I don't have is an ActiveX control for the biometric that I can use in my MVC application.
 4. What a possible solution that I hope should work is: making the Windows App do the Biometric stuff and communicate the results to the MVC app. 
Now, the problem is how to make the realtime communication between the two apps working? Is that approach right?
Has anyone of you experts done a similar thing before? Can anyone provide me with a sample application link that does similar stuff?
Hoping that you geeks out there will help me get out of the problem as you always have in the past. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do:

1 - Program a client app that connects to the biometric device using the SDK;
2 - Whenever a new scan event is triggered by the device launch the webpage to connect to your server through Https and broadcast the ID obtained from the device, I would use WebAPI and force SSL;
3 - Manage the ID from the server side to send a connection token (SSO style) to;

Comment: Thanks! Can you please share some more information on the 2nd point?

Comment: read this http://codebetter.com/johnvpetersen/2012/04/02/making-your-asp-net-web-apis-secure/ for encrypting your communication and instanciate a new webclient() to post the data from the installed application on the machine (The one that uses your device through the SDK)